# If a defendant was threatened with grievous bodily harm unless he caused grievous bodily harm to another, why can't he rely on necessity?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

Kindly see the embolded sentence. Why can't such a defendant rely on Necessity, but can rely on Duress of Circumstances?

> #### 2.5 Duress of Circumstances

> In some cases where the defendant does the lesser of two evils he or she will be able to rely on
> the defence of duress of circumstances. For example, in *Pipe v DPP*<sup>86</sup> a man was driving his ill
> son to hospital and broke the speed limit. Owen J held that the jury should have been allowed
> to consider whether he could rely on duress of circumstances (or necessity as he called it). As
> will be discussed in Section 5 of this chapter, duress provides a defence where the defendant
> reasonably believes that the circumstances are such that unless he or she commits a crime he
> or she or another will suffer death or serious injury and that a reasonable person in the same
> situation would have committed the crime. This defence clearly overlaps to some extent with
> necessity. Being faced with the threat of death which the defendant avoids by driving through
> a red light would fall under the defence of duress of circumstances; it would also be said to
> be the lesser of two evils. However, duress of circumstances is in some sense narrower and in
> some sense wider than necessity. It is narrower in that duress of circumstances is not available
> in order to avoid a threat less than death or grievous bodily harm **[abbreviated GBH]**. However, where it is
> available necessity may provide a defence even where the harm threatened is less than serious
> harm. Duress of circumstances is wider than a necessity defence would be, in that it covers
> the situation where the defendant reasonably believed there to be a threat of death or serious
> injury, even if there was in fact no such threat. A necessity defence would not cover such a
> situation.<sup>87</sup> Further, **if the defendant was threatened with grievous bodily harm unless he or
> she caused grievous bodily harm, although the two kinds of harm may be the same and so he
> or she may not be able to rely on necessity**, he or she may be able to rely on duress of circumstances
> and argue that a reasonable person would have given in to the threat.

> <sup>86</sup> [2012] EWHC 1821 (Admin).

Herring, *Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2020 9 ed). p 670.

Comment: The answer may lie in chapter 5 and/or the absent footnote 87 (which I suspect is case law concerning necessity - possibly *Cairns 1999?*)

Answer (score 2):

Because (at least in the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)) *duress* refers to being **compelled** to commit a crime **by another person** (e.g., by threats), while *necessity* refers to being forced to do **in response to circumstances** (e.g., running a red light to avoid getting hit by another vehicle).

See, e.g., [Justia](https://www.justia.com/criminal/defenses/duress/):

> The main difference is that duress means that the defendant committed a crime because someone directly forced them to do it. Necessity involves a choice between two bad alternatives that could not be avoided, which arose from the circumstances rather than the actions of a specific person.

This may not be true in England and Wales, though, as your example gives running a red light as duress of circumstances.